# If Statement issue or operator issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Need help to find out what wrong has happened? Resulting output doesn't cover less then condition.

Operator in javascript not working or if else is not working.

```
function set_shield(t_value){

    var shield = document.getElementById('set_shield');
    if(shield.value==0){
        alert('Keep Enter a Value')
        exit;
    }
    else if(isNaN(shield.value)) {
        alert('Keep Enter Only numeric value')
        exit;
    }
    else if(t_value < shield.value) {
        alert('gf')
        exit;
    }
    else {
        var ok = confirm("Are you sure want Lock Value?")
        if (ok) {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
        else {
            exit;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What even is `exit`?

Comment: put a SEMI COLON after every alert() in your js code @NikhilSolanki

Comment: @MalikAsifComsats While I agree, it won't change how this code executes.

Comment: Not Working.. with also putting SEMI COLON

Comment: seems like there is no issue other than `exit` which does not prevent it to display the alert box: http://jsfiddle.net/dxwmu4ub/

Comment: What is `t_value`?  If it's a string, it will be doing a string comparison with the `<` since `shield.value` is also a string (even if's a string representation of a number, it's still a string), so things like `"5" < "10" == false` start happening.  There is not enough context here to know what's happening, what's supposed to be happening, and why it is/isn't happening.

Comment: I think that your `exit`s should be `return`s. I think you are getting your programming languages mixed up. Really, you do not need anything there as your `if`/`else` statements will block other lines of code from being rendered.

Comment: I have tried this trick and works almost every time. Copy the document.getElementById("set_shield").value and replace it with all the shield.value @NikhilSolanki

Comment: Both "t_value" and "shield" is numeric. "shield"  is come from text box with id 'set_shield' by user enter able. here i want to compare both the values.

Comment: Your code works perfect. What is the t_value and the input box value you are testing for which your condition fails?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Impossible; `exit` isn't JavaScript. The conditionals will work (assuming reasonable values) but the console will show that it's not working "perfectly".

Comment: @DaveNewton Ran it on a test project and then commented :)

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Neat. But `exit` isn't JavaScript, and will report an error on the console in any reasonable JS environment, unless you define an `exit` function.

Comment: @DaveNewton Agreed. In the console of Chrome, it does show that error. However the code still executes correctly.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Not if there's anything after it. My point was that it doesn't execute perfectly, because it's invalid JS. There's no point in not telling the OP that it's broken as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force shield.value to int in every comparison, since you're using it as a numeric value.

```
parseInt(shield.value, 10)
```

example:

```
else if (parseInt(t_value, 10) < parseInt(shield.value, 10)) {
```

t_value is unkown for us, it might not need parseInt, but I assume it does.

Also `exit` is throwing a syntax error. Remove them all - not needed, does nothing.

Comment: Worth noting that the [recommendation is to use the radix parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) for `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bd61xv1z/3/

**HTML**

```
<input id="set_shield" type="text" value="0" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function set_shield(t_value){

                var shield = document.getElementById('set_shield');
                    if(shield.value==0){
                            alert('Keep Enter a Value');
                            }

                    else if(isNaN(parseInt(shield.value, 10)))
                            {
                            alert('Keep Enter Only numeric value');
                                }
                    else if(t_value < shield.value){
                            alert('gf');
                            }   
                    else{   

                            var ok = confirm("Are you sure want Lock Value?")
                                    if (ok)
                                    {
                                         alert("I am an alert box!");


                                        }
                                    else{

                                        }   

                            }
    }
```

Comment: check the console while running this code on the jsfiddle and you will see the error !

Comment: `exit` is not a thing.

Comment: Removed the   exit  but still the same as before

Comment: What happens when you try "less than"? What should happen?

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest you only use parseInt in one comparison. It's needed in them all